# Determining whether time series are related via a constant shift

Tags: r, time-series

Given two sets of time series observations $A$ and $B$, what test could I apply to demonstrate that the series are generated via a random process of the form $A:\{X_t\}$ and $B:\{X_t+k\}$ for some constant $k$?

Comment: Why not begin by plotting $(t, B_t-A_t)$ to see whether this is even reasonable to try?

Comment: I have plotted the differences between the series, and it seems like it may be constant (although decreasing slightly and with some noise), however I'm not sure how to formally test this fact.

Comment: One usually tests that with a paired-sample t test.  One of the preconditions is that the differences be independent, so with a time series you would want to test for independence first.  It usually suffices to show they aren't strongly correlated.

Comment: It is likely my misunderstanding, but would a paired-sample t test not give results of a significant difference between the two series if $k$ is large? As the difference between averages of each series could be arbitrarily large.

Comment: The larger $k$ gets, the *more* significant that test is likely to be.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called a [cross-correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation).
You'll find a lot of details if you read up on cross-correlation methods, but here's a quick example.
There is a lot more that could be said about the challanges of what you're trying to do (multiple comparisons, non-stationary time series, etc.), but I won't go into that here.

```
full_data = cumsum(rnorm(500))
k = 25
x = full_data[1:100]
offset_x = full_data[(1+k):(100+k)]
plot(x, type =  'b')
```

[image]

```
result = ccf(x, offset_x, lag.max = 50, plot = T)
```

[image]

```
result$lag[which.max(result$acf)]
# [1] 25
```

Comment: Cross correlation does not answer the question.  To see why not, consider two time series that approximate the same sine wave, plus a little white noise, but are displaced by an arbitrary constant: the cross-correlation at 0 lag (as well as most lags) is *huge* but the difference is a constant plus noise.

Comment: I presumed the OP meant an offset in time, rather than adding a constant to the values, but you're right, that's not what the question asks. I'll leave my answer here until this is clarified (and until I'm on a computer again).